# How send C# DateTime object into Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to send C# DateTime object into Javascript. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Do you want to pass it for display, as data for further processing?  Would it be part of a larger document?  Are you concerned about converting .NET's DateTime to JavaScript Date object?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which method you use to "send" the value to JavaScript (include, HTTP response,...), but I usually format the DateTime to yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss, pass it to the client, then I parse it with JavaScript using new Date(Date.parse({the date string}), which allows me to format it the way I want on the client-side, using the locale or other formatting constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much trivial:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var strServerTime = "<%=DateTime.Now%>";
alert("server time: " + strServerTime);
</script>
```

However, what you want to do with that date? If only to display, the above should suffice otherwise explain and we'll see how to proceed.

Comment: I'm assuming that the OT wants the DateTime object in C# to become DateTime object in Javascript

Comment: @the that's up to him to answer.. in such case it get complicated as server time usually does not match the client time, neither in format nor in the time itself.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a suitable string, and if you need to, have javascript parse it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now;
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Date", 
                String.Format(
                "var myDate = new Date({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6});",
                myDate.Year,
                myDate.Month,
                myDate.Day,
                myDate.Hour,
                myDate.Minute,
                myDate.Second,
                myDate.Millisecond
                ), true);
```

Or

```
var javaBaseDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
var myDate = DateTime.Now;
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Date", 
  String.Format(
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
  "var myDate = new Date({0});",
   (myDate - javaBaseDate).TotalMilliseconds
   ), true);
```

Comment: I tested the first example and it works with one problem: The JavaScript Month range is from 0-11 instead of 1-12. To fix this simply use `myDate.Month-1` on the server (C#)